# pem file from Microsoft serialized store (SST) files

Tags: windows

I have SST files form Microsoft, the contents of which I need to add to a Java truststore.

The problem is that all the tools that Microsoft provides add the certs from SST files to windows stores, so it's difficult to get PEM files from the SST files.

If I run certmgr.exe (not `certmgr.msc`), I can get the public key and all that but no certificates (in PEM or DER).

I saw bunch of VB scripts and PowerShell to load them using SST file into a `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection` object, but I still can't find a way to output as PEM (or DER) formatted certificates.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could use CAPI to open the SST file as a certificate store then enumerate over the certificates in the file.  The following code does this and outputs the certificates in DER form to a file using a SHA1 hash of the certificate as a filename.  The first argument is the output folder.  The remaining one or more arguments are your SST files.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include "windows.h"
#include "wincrypt.h"
#include "atlbase.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>

std::string GetHexRepresentation(const unsigned char * Bytes, size_t Length)
{
    std::ostringstream os;
    os.fill('0');
    os<<std::hex;
    for(const unsigned char * ptr=Bytes;ptr<Bytes+Length;ptr++)
        os<<std::setw(2)<<(unsigned int)*ptr;
    std::string retval = os.str();
    std::transform(retval.begin(), retval.end(),retval.begin(), ::toupper);
    return retval;
}

BOOL WriteToFileWithHashAsFilename(PCCERT_CONTEXT pPrevCertContext, TCHAR* outputDir)
{
#undef RETURN
#define RETURN(rv) \
{ \
     if( hHash ) CryptDestroyHash(hHash); \
     if( hProv ) CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0); \
    return rv; \
} 

     HCRYPTPROV hProv = 0;
     HCRYPTHASH hHash = 0;

     BYTE byteFinalHash[20];
     DWORD dwFinalHashSize = 20;

     if (!CryptAcquireContext(&hProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))
     {
         std::cout << "CryptAcquireContext failed: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
         RETURN(FALSE);
     }

     if (!CryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_SHA1, 0, 0, &hHash))
     {
         std::cout << "CryptCreateHash failed: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
         RETURN(FALSE);
     }

     if (!CryptHashData(hHash, pPrevCertContext->pbCertEncoded, pPrevCertContext->cbCertEncoded, 0))
     {
         std::cout << "CryptHashData failed: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
         RETURN(FALSE);
     }

     if (!CryptGetHashParam(hHash, HP_HASHVAL, byteFinalHash, &dwFinalHashSize, 0))
     {
         std::cout << "CryptGetHashParam failed: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
         RETURN(FALSE);
     }

     std::string strHash = GetHexRepresentation(byteFinalHash, dwFinalHashSize);
     std::wostringstream filename;
     filename << outputDir << strHash.c_str() << ".der" <<std::ends;

     FILE* f = _wfopen(filename.str().c_str(), L"wb+");
     if(!f)
     {
         std::wcout << "Failed to open file for writing: " << filename.str().c_str() << std::endl;
         RETURN(FALSE);
     }
     int bytesWritten = fwrite(pPrevCertContext->pbCertEncoded, 1, pPrevCertContext->cbCertEncoded, f);
     fclose(f);
     if(bytesWritten != pPrevCertContext->cbCertEncoded)
     {
         std::cout << "Failed to write file" << std::endl;
         RETURN(FALSE);
     }

     RETURN(TRUE); 
}  

//usage: DumpCertsFromSst <output directory> <SST file 1> ... <SST file n>
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;   
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES));
    sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;  

    if(argc < 3)
    {
        std::cout << "At least two arguments must be provided: outputDirectory sstFile1 ... sstFileN etc" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    TCHAR* outputDir = argv[1];

    for(int ii = 2; ii < argc; ++ii)
    {
        HANDLE       hFile = NULL;
        HCERTSTORE   hFileStore = NULL;
        LPCWSTR      pszFileName = argv[ii];

        //Open file
        hFile = CreateFile(pszFileName, GENERIC_READ, 0, &sa, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);                      
        if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile)
        {
            std::wcout << "Failed to open file: " << pszFileName  << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            std::wcout << "Processing file: " << pszFileName  << std::endl;
        }

        //open certificate store
        hFileStore = CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_FILE, 0, NULL, CERT_STORE_READONLY_FLAG, hFile);
        if(NULL == hFileStore)
        {
            CloseHandle(hFile);
            continue;
        }

        int count = 0;
        PCCERT_CONTEXT pPrevCertContext = NULL;
        pPrevCertContext = CertEnumCertificatesInStore(hFileStore, pPrevCertContext);
        while(NULL != pPrevCertContext)
        {
            if(WriteToFileWithHashAsFilename(pPrevCertContext, outputDir))
                ++count;

            pPrevCertContext = CertEnumCertificatesInStore(hFileStore, pPrevCertContext);
        }

        std::wcout << "Wrote " << count << " certificates" << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        CertCloseStore(hFileStore, 0);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The challenge is to export all the local certs as trusted certs for each JDK on the system. The following [PowerShell Core](https://superuser.com/questions/1621460/whats-the-difference-between-powershell-desktop-and-powershell-core) snippet can achieve this in an idempotent way (multiple runs will produce the same result):

```pwsh
#Requires -Version 6.0
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator

$jdkPaths = Get-Command -Name java -All | Where-Object -FilterScript { Test-Path -Path (Join-Path -Path ($_ | Split-Path -Parent) -ChildPath 'keytool.exe') } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path | Split-Path -Parent | Sort-Object -Unique

# Calculate existing certs first
$certBag = [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag[PSCustomObject]]::new()
$jdkPaths | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    # Parallel work for each JDK, since their respective stores do not conflict
    $certBag = $using:certBag
    $_ | Push-Location
    $keytoolCerts = .\keytool.exe -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -list 2>$null | Select-Object -Skip 5  # The first 4 lines are information messages followed by empty newline
    #region Parse the output of keytool.exe
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $keytoolCerts.Count; $i += 2) {
        $certBag.Add( 
            (
                $keytoolCerts[$i] | Select-String -Pattern '(?<alias>[^,]+), (?<date>\w{3}\. \d+, \d{4}), (?<storetype>[^,]+)' | ForEach-Object {
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        Keystore    = $PWD
                        Alias       = $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value  # This is the only information we care about, but I parse of the rest of the output for funsies
                        Date        = [datetime]::Parse($_.Matches.Groups[2].Value)
                        StoreType   = $_.Matches.Groups[3].Value
                        Fingerprint = (
                            $keytoolCerts[$i + 1] | Select-String -Pattern '[^\(]+\(([^\)]+)\): (.*)' | ForEach-Object {
                                [PSCustomObject]@{
                                    Algorithm = $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
                                    Bytes     = [byte[]]($_.Matches.Groups[2].Value -split ':' -replace '^', '0x')
                                }
                            }
                        ) 
                    }
                }
            ) 
        )
    }
    #endregion Parse the output of keytool.exe
    Pop-Location
} -ThrottleLimit $env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS

# Retrieve all certificates under the Cert:\ path (including subdirectories), with a valid Thumbprint property.
$certs = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\ -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Thumbprint } 
$certs | ForEach-Object { 
    $thumb = $_.Thumbprint  # This is a hash of the certificate, and is unique
    $alias = $_.FriendlyName  # Most readable for humans
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($alias)) {
        $alias = $_.Subject -replace '\W'  # Slightly less readable for humans
    }
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($alias)) {
        $alias = $thumb  # Least readable for humans
    }
    $export = $_ | Export-Certificate -Type CERT -FilePath "$env:TEMP\$thumb.cer" -Force  # Export the certificate to a temporary file

    # Get all the JDK paths
    $jdkPaths | ForEach-Object  {
        $_ | Push-Location
        $existingKeys = $certBag | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.Keystore -like $PWD -and $_.Alias -like $alias }
        if ($null -ne $existingKeys) {
            # Remove the existing certificate from the keystore
            .\keytool.exe -trustcacerts -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -delete -alias "$alias"
        }
        Write-Host "Adding certificate " -ForegroundColor DarkCyan -NoNewline
        Write-Host "$alias" -ForegroundColor Cyan -NoNewline
        Write-Host " to keystore " -ForegroundColor DarkCyan -NoNewline
        Write-Host "$PWD" -ForegroundColor Cyan -NoNewline
        Write-Host "..." -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
        .\keytool.exe -trustcacerts -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -importcert -alias "$alias" -file "$export"
        Pop-Location
    }
    Remove-Item -Path $export -Force
}
```

A little bit of modification will be required to make the above compatible with with PowerShell 5.1 or older. I have also reproduced this in [[image: GitHub Logo]the following GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/mavaddat/a88d7938bffb8e439b6b9d887406f41c).